# JDBC API specification and implementation

Tags: java, jdbc

I was going through JDBC API's (mainly java.sql package) after writing some simple JDBC programs.

For example, in java.sql, the below is the declaration:

```
public interface Connection extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable
```

So, as per my understanding, these specifications have to be implemented by database vendors, in the form of JDBC drivers.

In my sample program i used H2 db, so i downloaded the JDBC driver.

Now, this jar should have implementation of java.sql.Connection, and this is what i saw in the .jar (jdbc driver) for this (under package --> org.h2.jdbc):

```
public class org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection extends org.h2.message.TraceObject implements java.sql.Connection {
```

The jdbc driver jar does implement java.sql.Connection, as expected; however where does it get java.sql.Connection from? (it simply implements java.sql.Connection), where is the definition of java.sql.Connection coming from?

Any pointers to clear this doubt would be helpful.

Comment: As I also commented on the answer: you are using reverse engineered source of H2 instead of the actual source, which is usually easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the JDK, since you were able to look at [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) in the [JDK javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply; so it means when they compile, they get definition from the JDK itself.  If that is the case, i believe in the source code of the implementer, they would have statement like this: import java.sql.Connection.

Comment: Yes, of course. Unless they're masochist and prefer typing java.sql.Connection every time.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, downloaded mysql Connector/J source code to get a feel how they implement. Thanks again!

Comment: @vipinkoul Sometimes people don't use imports and use the fully qualified name of the class to avoid name-conflicts (eg MySQL has called their implementation classes the same as the interfaces in `java.sql`). Although in your specific case I guess you didn't actually download the sources, and have your IDE reverse engineer the Java code as the actual source isn't the same and does use imports: https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcConnection.java

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Exactly i used eclipse IDE to get the source (albeit small source it shows). I otherwise downloaded Connector/J to understand it. Thanks a lot for sharing your expert advise. Best Regards